# Content of page (buttons, images, etc.) goes off when browser is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css, wrapper

I'm encountering issues when it comes to changing the browser size because the content starts going off. I've done some research and tried with #wrapper but I cant' figure it out. How do I do to scale my page content when the browser is resized?

http://philome.la/gapp06gt/c3gua9/play

```css
body {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  background-size:98%;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position:center;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

tw-link {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 1.5em;
  margin: auto;
  border: ridge #191970 0.4em;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}

tw-passage {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid #000 0.05em;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  font-family: Lucida Console;
  ;font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: #000 0.2em 0.2em 0;
  *{margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}}

tw-icon {
  opacity: 1;
  color: red;
}

tw-sidebar {
  color:;
  border:;
  padding-bottom: 0.8em;
  border-radius: 25%;
  background-image:;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Question is too broad, there are too many valid solutions. You should explain what you want it to look like, then we can help

Comment: `tw-story`, `tw-passage`, `tw-align` and `tw-expression` are not valid HTML elements. I recommend using `div` elements with classes, like this: `<div class="tw-story"></div>`.

Comment: @JuanMendes I simply want when somebody makes the browser smaller the page to keep it's original aspect, meaning everything to get smaller at the same time too

Comment: @MarkPlewis I'm using an online gaming-base page (twinery.org) and that's how it's required to be entered in the css to keep the syntaxis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS media queries to progressively widen your container and reduce it's padding, as the viewport becomes more narrow. The idea is to adapt the layout to whatever is most appropriate for each screen size, so simply scaling down your entire layout isn't necessarily ideal.

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  tw-story { width: 70%; }
  tw-passage { padding 5%; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 850px) {
  tw-story { width: 80%; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 750px) {
  tw-story { width: 90%; }
}
/* etc. */
```

You can also make the `img` elements responsive, like this:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

If you don't want to use media queries to progressively change the size of your text, then you could try the [FitText jQuery plugin](http://fittextjs.com/). I recommend only using this on heading text through, not your smaller body copy. The author even issues a warning against this: "Don't you dare let us catch you using FitText on paragraph text. This is for gigantic display text only!"

Comment: Almost got it.. with the .img elements, how do I specify size, etc. to one specific image only and not all of them?

Comment: Add `class` or `id` attributes to your `img` elements, like this: `<img id="my-photo">`, then use that identifier to select it in your CSS, like this: `#my-photo { width: 100%; height: auto; }`

Comment: Thank ypu very much @MarkPlewis, done it. I used a combination of img attributes as you indicated and max-width,  min-width:to the main body.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into the  [position property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: I've seen that, and I believe it should be positioning fixed but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

So I looked a bit over your code, and I don't get one thing. on `tw-align` you have `max-width:50%`. Any reason for that? If not, change it to `max-width:100%` on all of the `tw-align`.

On 700px resolution, you should decrease the padding of `tw-passage` to `1em` or something else, and your content should be responsive.